# three js animation action not animating

Tags: javascript, three.js

Okay I have spent a seriously large amount of time on this... I have read as many docs make sense and an equal amount of source code...

I have a json loader and a blender animation

its a simple walk cycle....

```
    /******************************************************************/

       // name      :buffer_set_up
       // params    : none 
       // functions : creates the buffer to adjust 
       // returns   : nothing
       this.buffer_set_up = function() {   

          this.add('manager', new THREE.LoadingManager());
          this.get_setting('loader').load('sites/all/themes/brain/models/sitespace.json', function(geometry, materials) {

            materials.forEach(function (material) {
                material.skinning = true;
            });

             var character = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(
                 geometry,
                  new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)
            );

              closed_object.get_setting('scene').add(character);

              closed_object.set_up_model_animation(character);

          });      
       }


       // name : set_up_model_animation
       // params : model  is the model that is currently animating
       // functions : intitiates the animation mixer
       // return : nothing
       this.set_up_model_animation = function(model) {

            this.add('mixer', new THREE.AnimationMixer( model ) );

            this.add('walk', closed_object.get_setting("mixer").clipAction(model.geometry.animations[1]) );        

            this.get_setting('walk').play(); 

       }

///// ******** rAF ************* //////
   // name : animate
   // params: none;
   // function: calls the looping animation sequence where rendering takes place
   // returns nothing 
   this.animate = function() {

       requestAnimationFrame(function() {
          closed_object.animate();               // calls a frame reliable function
       });

       // wait for the animation mixer to catch up   
       if(typeof closed_object.get_setting('mixer') != 'undefined') {

           /// the docs say to pass into the mixer the delta. [new time - old time] and scale that by the mixers time scale
           // closed_object.get_setting('mixer').timeScale * closed_object.get_setting('clock').getDelta()
           closed_object.get_setting('mixer').update( closed_object.get_setting('clock').getDelta() );

       } 

       closed_object.get_setting('renderer').render(
           closed_object.get_setting('scene'),
           closed_object.get_setting('camera'),
       );

    }   



    /***********************************************************/
```

my site loads the model... I have no errors but my animation action is not doing anything